# Parsing XDocument using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am doing the following query on an `XDocument`. The last level `.Descendants("Instance")` yields a list of XElements of the form:

```
<Instance>filepath1</Instance>
<Instance>filepath2</Instance>
<Instance>filepath3</Instance>
<Instance>filepath4</Instance>
```

Query

```
 List<string> fileNames = xDoc.Descendants("Main")
                       .FirstOrDefault()
                       .Descendants("SecondLevel")
                       .FirstOrDefault()
                       .Descendants("Instance")
                       .Select().ToList(); //this line is not correct. Need to get the instances node values as List<string>
```

How can I store the values `filepath1`, `filepath2`.. in the `List<string>`?

Comment: Something like `Select(x=>x.Value)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using

```
 ....
  .Descendants("Instance")
  .Select(e => e.Value) // project to the string values
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Forgive my ignorance, what is that syntax. It looks like writing anonymous functions with Lamda expressions.

Comment: It is a lambda expression. It Converts the found XElements into their string Values. Read up on basic LINQ, any tutorial will do.